# Open FilePath For Input works, but Open FilePath For Output doesn't

Tags: excel, macos, vba

I'm having an issue with a VBA macro in MS Excel 2016 on Mac. When I open a file on a network share for Input, it opens and reads the file no problem. When I try to open the same file for Output, I get error 52: Bad file name or number.

I know it has nothing to do with a limit on the number of characters, and I tried it locally and it works both ways.

The problem really only occurs when the file I want to write to is living on a networked share folder, and only on Mac. I don't think it's a permissions issue, since I've set the folder to allow read/write for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue by saving the file locally first, then copying it to the network share, like this:

```
Open FilePath2 For Output As #1
Print #1, "Hello"
Close (1)
FileCopy FilePath2, FilePath
```